# Del studio 15 with ubuntu 14.04 - wifi frequently disconnects

Tags: 14.04, wireless, dell, iwlwifi

I have the usual problem of wifi randomly disconnecting and it won't reconnect until I restart my machine. Sometimes, restart also does not help and it again randomly starts to work.

I have tried the usual

`sudo sh -c 'modprobe -r iwlwifi && modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1'`

but that hasn't helped.

Following are the messages from my syslog, during the time when my machine tries to connect to wifi and fails-

```
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'House Targaryen'
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'House Targaryen' has security, but secrets are required.
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'House Targaryen' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'House Targaryen'
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
May 28 22:42:22 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 28 22:42:48 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long, failing activation.
May 28 22:42:48 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> failed (reason 'SSID not found') [50 120 53]
May 28 22:42:48 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 28 22:42:48 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> Marking connection 'House Targaryen' invalid.
May 28 22:42:48 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for connection 'House Targaryen'
May 28 22:42:48 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
May 28 22:42:48 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
May 28 22:42:48 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
May 28 22:42:48 agniva-studio NetworkManager[1046]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
```

Any help on this is appreciated.